# xlwings issue using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5, xlwings

I'm making a database-ish python 3 program that saves `tkinter` entries into an excel file. I really like using `xlwings`, so please find the solution with `xlwings`. Anyways, here is the issue:

```
from tkinter import *
import xlwings as xw    
def save() :
    entrylist = [entry1.get(), entry2.get(), entry3.get(), entry4.get(), entry5.get(), 
    entry6.get(), entry7.get(), entry8.get(), entry9.get()]

        if len(entrylist[i]) != 0 and entry2.get() == entry3.get():
            teller = int(xw.Range('M1').value) + 1

            for i in range(0,3):
                rowlist = ["A"+ str(teller), "B"+ str(teller), "C"+str(teller), "D"+str(teller)]
                rowcode = "\'"+ rowlist[i] + "\'"
                xw.Range(rowcode).value = entrylist[i]

        xw.Range('M1').value = teller
        wb.save('klantendatabase.xlsx')
```

Now the problem is that the following piece of code is not allowed:

```
xw.Range(rowcode).value = entrylist[i]
```

This is only allowed like this (A1 is an example cellnumber from the excel file)::

```
xw.Range('A1').value = entrylist[i]
```

Is there a way to make the `xw.Range().value` take a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set up your service to run on an https set up rather than http. Generally port 8080 is most reliable for security. After that run your code in debug mode and run a database diff from your source code. This should take care of all the log messages.

Comment: Im sorry but that's not what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap `rowcode` with quotation marks, they are already strings. This works:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Workbook()
rowcode = 'A1'
xw.Range(rowcode).value = 'some value'
```

Although it might be easier in your case to use indices like so: `xw.Range((i,j)).value`